# preg_match doesnt work with my array

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I got just a test pattern here, but it does disallow spaces.

```
$myarray[]='s s';
if (preg_match('/[^\d\w\(\)\[\]\.\-]+/',$myarray)>0) echo 'yes';
```

This does nothing, but

```
$test='s s';
if (preg_match('/[^\d\w\(\)\[\]\.\-]+/',$test)>0) echo 'yes';
```

This works fine...
I dont understand why it doesn't work with my array?

Comment: If you look at the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) You will see that the function only accepts a string as subject so it isn't strange at all it doesn't work :P

Comment: preg-match doesn't work with arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preg_match doesn't accept an array as input, just a single string. You'd need to do something like...

```
$matched = no;
foreach($myarray as $x) {
    if (preg_match('/[^\d\w\(\)\[\]\.\-]+/',$x)>0) $matched = true;
}
if($matched) echo 'yes';
```

To do it in one step:

```
function preg_match_any($regex,$array) {
    foreach($array as $x) {
        if (preg_match($regex,$x)>0) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//Then to call it just something like:
if (preg_match_any('/[^\d\w\(\)\[\]\.\-]+/',$myarray)) echo 'yes';
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, got it, I guess I'll stick with this one if it can't be done in a single call. Thanks! :)

Comment: You could easily create a simple function that does this for you - I'll update my answer...

Comment: Oh well, thanks for pointing out, I just end up making the function myself, didn't think you would edit your post :P here's what I got:

        function u($in){foreach($in as $x =>$a) {
        if (preg_match('/[^\d\w\(\)\[\]\.\-]+/',$a)>0) return(true);}};
        if (u($input)) echo 'yes';

Answer (score 2):

You can't perform an operation like that on an array. As you can see in [the documentation on `preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match), it takes a string as the second parameter, not an array.

> ```
> int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject
>       [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
> ```

Instead, you have to tell it which element you want to make the operation on.

If you want to do this to just one element of an array, just use its index. E.g. the first element will be `$myarray[0]`, so the following should work:

```
if (preg_match('/[^\d\w\(\)\[\]\.\-]+/',$myarray[0])>0) echo 'yes';
```

If you on the other hand wish to do it to every element in your array, you can either

- **create a foreach loop**

  ```
  foreach ($myarray as $element) {
    if (preg_match('/[^\d\w\(\)\[\]\.\-]+/',$element)>0) echo 'yes';
  }
  ```
- **use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) and a callback function**

  ```
  function match_callback($element) {
    if (preg_match('/[^\d\w\(\)\[\]\.\-]+/',$element)>0) echo 'yes';
  }
  array_map('match_callback',$myarray);
  ```

Comment: thanks, well, I wanted just to get a single yes, it if any of array elements matches a pattern.

Comment: @user1125062 If that's the case, just use the `foreach` loop. Remember to call `break` if a match is found, otherwise the loop will go through the rest of the array after a match and possibly write 'yes' multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an array as your subject as `preg_match` only accepts a string. You can use an anonymous function (php 5.3+):

```
$ret = array_map(function($element) {    
    return preg_replace('/[^\d\w\(\)\[\]\.\-]+/', '', $element) > 0; 
}, $myarray );
```